# Remove duplicates from an array of objects

Tags: android, arraylist, duplicates

I have a number of objects in array list . which has some duplicates. I want to remove the duplicates from it. 
I tried with my below code.

below is my PhoneContacts model class

```
public class PhoneContactsModel  {
private boolean isChecked;
String contactName;
String contactNumber;

public PhoneContactsModel(String contactName, String contactNumber, boolean isChecked) {
    this.contactName = contactName;
    this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    this.isChecked = isChecked;
}


protected PhoneContactsModel(Parcel in) {
    isChecked = in.readByte() != 0;
    contactName = in.readString();
    contactNumber = in.readString();
}



@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof PhoneContactsModel)) return false;

    PhoneContactsModel class1 = (PhoneContactsModel) o;

    return contactNumber.equals(class1.contactNumber);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return contactNumber.hashCode();
}


public boolean isChecked() {
    return isChecked;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    isChecked = checked;
}

public String getContactName() {
    return contactName;
}

public void setContactName(String contactName) {
    this.contactName = contactName;
}

public String getContactNumber() {
    return contactNumber;
}

public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
    this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
}
```

}

I have tried tree set like below

```
public ArrayList<PhoneContactsModel> removeDuplicates(ArrayList<PhoneContactsModel> list) {

    Set set = new TreeSet(new Comparator() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            if (((PhoneContactsModel) o1).getContactNumber().equalsIgnoreCase(((PhoneContactsModel) o2).getContactNumber())) {
                return 0;
            }
            return 1;
        }
    });
    set.addAll(list);
    list.clear();

    final ArrayList newList = new ArrayList(set);
    return newList;
}
```

I want to filter that arrayList according to phone number.
But I got no chnge even I used HashSet.
Please help me any suggestions, that if I did any thing wrong. 
any Suggestions were accepted.

Comment: The real question is: If you do not want duplicates, why are you adding them to the list?.  You should be scrutinizing your data more carefully. The problem is you need to be using a unified value format or at least forcing one on your data. I see many reasons why your code will not work. But knowing where and how you get your data and in what format it is in would narrow the possibilities down considerably.

Comment: @Barns, actually I am getting duplicate contacts while fetching contacts from my mobile. that is my context to this my problem.

Comment: With `String` values it is particularly difficult for a machine to find duplicates.  Eg. Humans can see that "TOM Smith", "Tom Smith", "Tom  Smith" and "Tom R. Smith" all probably refer to the same person. The same with contact number: "01149 221 99999", "+49 221 99999", "0221 99999" and "0221/99999" also easy for a Human to detect as duplicates. Any data that has been entered into a system by human hands will have this issue. It is your job as a developer to develop a scheme by which you can force a unified format model.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

> 1. Entity class `PhoneContactsModel`

```
public class PhoneContactsModel implements Parcelable{
    private boolean isChecked;
    String contactName;
    String contactNumber;

    public PhoneContactsModel(String contactName, String contactNumber, boolean isChecked) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
        this.isChecked = isChecked;
    }


    protected PhoneContactsModel(Parcel in) {
        isChecked = in.readByte() != 0;
        contactName = in.readString();
        contactNumber = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (isChecked ? 1 : 0));
        dest.writeString(contactName);
        dest.writeString(contactNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public static final Creator<PhoneContactsModel> CREATOR = new Creator<PhoneContactsModel>() {
        @Override
        public PhoneContactsModel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new PhoneContactsModel(in);
        }

        @Override
        public PhoneContactsModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new PhoneContactsModel[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof PhoneContactsModel)) return false;

        PhoneContactsModel class1 = (PhoneContactsModel) o;

        return contactNumber.equals(class1.contactNumber);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return contactNumber.hashCode();
    }


    public boolean isChecked() {
        return isChecked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        isChecked = checked;
    }

    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    public String getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }

    public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }


}
```

> 2. To Remove duplicates

```
   // I have added some dummy data
   ArrayList<PhoneContactsModel> phoneContactsModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        phoneContactsModelArrayList.add(new PhoneContactsModel("User","123456789",true));
        phoneContactsModelArrayList.add(new PhoneContactsModel("User","123456789",true));
        phoneContactsModelArrayList.add(new PhoneContactsModel("User","123456789",true));
        phoneContactsModelArrayList.add(new PhoneContactsModel("User1","123456788",true));
        phoneContactsModelArrayList.add(new PhoneContactsModel("User2","123456787",true));
        phoneContactsModelArrayList.add(new PhoneContactsModel("User3","123456786",true));


        //uniques list
        List<PhoneContactsModel> result = new ArrayList<PhoneContactsModel>();
        // to just remove duplicates
        Set<String> numbers= new HashSet<String>();

        for( PhoneContactsModel phoneContactsModel: phoneContactsModelArrayList ) {
            if( numbers.add( phoneContactsModel.getContactNumber() )) {
                result.add( phoneContactsModel);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sure, let me know with your response

Comment: comment overrided equals and hashCode method in PhoneContactsModel

Comment: Can you please post your both list original and result?